# Vue not updating on property change

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I've got an index component that contains this, in part:

```
<template>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li v-if="state.user"><a @click.stop="do_logout" v-link="{ path: '/'}">Logout {{ state.user.display_name }}</a></li>
    <li v-else v-link-active><a v-link="{ path: '/login' }">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <router-view></router-view>
<template>

<script>

import state from '../state';
import { logout } from '../actions';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      state
    };
  },
  methods: {
    do_logout() {
      logout().then(() => this.$router.go('/'));
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

And I've got a login component that looks like this:

```
<template>
  <form class="form-signin" @submit.prevent="do_login">
    <input type="email" v-model="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" v-model="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>

import { login } from '../../actions';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    do_login() {
      login(this.email, this.password).then(() => this.$router.go('/'));
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

My login and logout methods look like this:

```
import state from './state';

export const login = (email, pwd) => {
  return fetch_post_json('/api/login', {
    email,
    pwd
  }).then(j => state.user = j.user);
};

export const logout = () => _fetch('/api/logout', 'GET', null, false).then(() => state.user = null);
```

Logging out works fine; clicking the link changes the text and presents the "Login" link. Logging in succeeds in logging in, in the Javascript, but doesn't update the link. I'm forced to reload the page to get the page to render correctly. Why?

Comment: You state in login and logout is not observed, since it is never added to a vue.js component. What you're doing resembles a mixin, so I would suggest just using one instead: https://vuejs.org/guide/mixins.html

Comment: I don't understand how changing my example to a mixin solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, after looking at your code again, I think Bill Criswell was onto something with the arrow function. I'm not sure if vue needs the component context in the data function or not though. My first though was that the login component doesn't consume the `state`, but since it's already observed by the index component, it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: I changed the data function (and updated the example). I get the same behavior. Logout updates the address bar, while login doesn't without a refresh.

Comment: Looks like your promise doesn't get resolved after fetching. Can you check (using a `debugger` statement for example), if you ever reach the `.then(j => state.user = j.user)` callback?

Comment: That was it. It was returning successfully, but didn't have the correct property set. It's working now.